# Google sheet average function results the wrong average value

Tags: google-sheets, average

I am trying the average function to calculate the average of the number in column, but it gives the wrong result. All are numbers, I have also checked by applying ISNUMER() function.

below is the screenshot

[image: Average function result]

Actual average value of A1 to A3 should be 60074.67, but average function gives different result.

What is wrong in my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are only calculating the average of cells A1 and A3.
For the whole range try

```
=AVERAGE(A1:A3)
```

and see if that helps?

Comment: @Sagarvagela Or even AVERAGE(A1,A2,A3) will work but more typing. Knowing the difference between , and : is useful and applies to all functions.